# simply print a component in java with a diagonal line

Tags: java, graphics, components

I'm a beginner trying to print a basic window with a line 0,0,500,500.
I've tried validate, doLayout, printAll.  I am unsure about the g in the printAll.  I can't find anywhere that says what it is. ??

```
package helloprogram;    
import java.awt.Graphics.*;

/**
 *
 * @author jglvn
 */

class Component{

void setSize(int width, int height){     }

void setBounds(int x, int y){       }

void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){       }

void setBackground(int r, int g, int b){       }

void validate(){       }

void doLayout(){       }

void printAll(Graphics g){     }

} 

public class HelloProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Component canvas = new Component();
    canvas.setSize(500, 500);
    canvas.setBounds(300, 300);
    canvas.setBackground(153,153,153);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 500, 500);
    canvas.doLayout();
    canvas.validate();
    canvas.printAll(g);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by printing? Really want to print to a printer device or you want to show something in a frame?

Answer (score 1):

It seams you want to draw a line in a frame. If this is the case, you should go for some container like a `JPanel`. You want to `paint` something on the panel, you should override the `paint` method:

Here is a sample code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawLinePanel extends JPanel{
private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    f.add(new DrawLinePanel(new Point(100, 100), new Point(500, 500)));
    f.setVisible(true);
}

private Point pointA;
private Point pointB;

public DrawLinePanel(Point pointA, Point pointB) {
    this.pointA = pointA;
    this.pointB = pointB;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    //

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawLine(pointA.x, pointA.y, pointB.x, pointB.y);
}
}
```

Some advice:

1. Don't make the frame visible before you do all your graphics.
2. Don't mix the `Component` sub classes like `Frame` or `Panel` with `JComponent` sub classes like `JFrame` or `JPanel`.

Hope this would be helpful.